# German term for literature of aging

Tags: compound, literature

Long ago in a book I can no longer access, I spotted a German term for the genre of literature that focuses on aging or elderly characters, including their lives and emotional journeys. I expect that it would be a compound word that ends in "Roman," but I can't say for sure. Could it include the word "Verfallserscheinung," indicating decline or deterioration? This is only a guess on my part.

Comment: [Entwicklungsroman](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entwicklungsroman) is an earlier phase, typically becomning an adult and making first steps towards independence.

Answer (score 4):

The book *[Altwerden ist das Schönste und Dümmste, was einem passieren kann](https://www.amazon.de/Altwerden-Sch%C3%B6nste-D%C3%BCmmste-einem-passieren/dp/3896841602)* by [Reimer Gronemeyer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reimer_Gronemeyer) contains the term ***Geronto-Literatur***. This is the only such term that I could find, and the only usage of that term.

In German, the following terms are commonly used in relation to old age and getting older:

- *[Seneszenz](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Seneszenz)* "aging"
- *Geronto-* "of or related to old age or aging", e.g. in *[Gerontologie](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gerontologie)*
- *[Älterwerden](https://www.dwds.de/wb/%C3%84lterwerden)* "getting older", e.g. in *Die Kunst des Älterwerdens*
- *Altern* "getting older", e.g. in *Physiologie des Alterns*

The two german nouns *Altern* and *Älterwerden* are not commonly used to create compounds but rather in phrases. I tried a few searches of compounds and phrases with *Literatur* and *Roman* but found nothing. Your best bet would be to try and remember the book title and look at it in the Amazon preview or Google books.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, the term you're looking for is

> Seniorenroman -  senior citizen novel

Quoting [zeit.de](https://www.zeit.de/2016/40/seniorenroman-genre-literatur-unterhaltung)

> Es gibt ein neues literarisches Unterhaltungsgenre: der lustige Seniorenroman. Sein Entstehen dürfte auf das Jahr 2009 zurückgehen.
>
> There is a new literary entertainment genre: the funny senior citizen novel. Its origin should go back to the year 2009.

An example of this is Jonas Jonasson's "The Hundred-Year-Old Man Who Climbed Out the Window and Disappeared"